# Maximum absolute and relative error of IEEE-754 single precision representation?

Tags: floating-point, ieee-754, ieee

I'm looking to find the maximum overall absolute and relative error of IEEE-754 single precision representation. Sign: 1 bit, Exponent: 8 bits, Significand: 23 bits.

I understood that when normalised, the maximum number of digits in the significand would be 23 (and we assume a sign bit and exponent of 8 obviously). Hence if any extra digits turned up, then the error would propagate from 2^-24 onwards i.e. 2^-24, 2^-25, 2^-26... Hence I completed a geometric infinite sum of this to find an error: so i got 2^-23. However, I'm unsure whether this is correct for the relative error. Relative error would be the ((true value-given value)/true value)*100. I'm not sure if this is a wrong approach.

Additionally, I'm confused on how to find an absolute error. Could anyone assist please. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This was a part of a question. And this was a subpart: Find the maximum absolute error of IEEE-754 single precision representation. The first part was:  binary representation of -6.875 with IEEE754 so I had a similar reasoning to you. How about relative error? Would my answer be correct for that?

Comment: Well, 6.875 has an exact representation, so both the absolute and relative error there are 0.  But I think I have to retract my speculation about 1e50.  For any number within range (±1e38), it's either representable exactly, or it has an absolute and a relative error.  The maximum absolute error will occur in the last binade, [1,2)×2¹²⁷.  Off the top of my head, I don't know how to compute the maximum relative error.

Comment: Thinking about it a little more: I would check the relative error for numbers near the ends of the highest binade, the binade near 1, the smallest normal binade, and the subnormal binade.  The maximum relative error has just about got to be at one of those 8 spots.  (But I could be wrong.)

Comment: You need to clarify the question. First, are you asking what is the maximum absolute error and the maximum relative error when any real number is converted to the nearest value representable in IEEE-754 binary32? (Alternatives could be you are asking what are the maximum errors when you perform certain operations or certain sequences of operations with various constraints on the data.)

Comment: If you are asking something along those lines, you probably want to bound the question somewhat. Because let’s say you convert 2^500 to binary32. The two nearest representable values are 2^128−2^104 (because that is the largest finite value representable in binary32) and ∞. For this conversion, the rounding rules produce ∞, so the absolute error is ∞−2^500 = ∞. So the largest possible absolute error is infinity. And that also has a relative error of infinity.

Comment: Okay, let’s say we stay in range of the numbers that round to finite results. Consider 2^−150. That is exactly halfway between zero and the next representable number, 2^−149. When converted to binary32, it is rounded to zero. That is a tiny absolute error, 2^−150, but the relative error is 100%. So the maximum relative error, even for just finite results, is at least 100%. You might want to consider only numbers that round to non-zero *normal* results. Non-zero numbers below 2^−126 in magnitude are *subnormal* and involve larger than normal errors.

Comment: By the way, the binary32 format has 24-bit significands, not 23. 23 bits are encoded in the primary significand field, and one is encoded via the exponent field.

Answer (score 0):

All *finite*  [IEEE-754 single precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) are exact.  There is no *error* in the value itself.

A calculation/conversion may incur an error as there are only about 2<sup>32</sup> different IEEE-754 single precision values and there are infinite possible calculations results.  Typically a nearby single precision value is selected when the true result is not encodable.

If we limit the discussion to calculation results that are within a pair of finite single precision values, then the error could be at most 1.0 [ULP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place)<sup>*1</sup>.

Note: finite range +/-3.4028235... × 10<sup>38</sup> or `FLT_MAX`

Within that range, the absolute difference between the true result and the encoded single precision is then at most `FLT_MAX - next_smallest_float(FLOAT_MAX)`.  This is close to `FLOAT_MAX * pow(2,-24)` (about 2.03 * 10<sup>31</sup>).  Single precision has a 24-bit significand (23-bits explicitly encoded, 1 implied).

Outside that range the absolute error can be infinite.

For many calculations, when the results are in the [normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format#Exponent_encoding) single precision range, the *relative* error is within `1.0 * ULP` of the correct answer<sup>*1</sup>.  For transcendental calculations like `sine`, the error is within `2.0 * ULP` of the correct answer.  That can be much worse for weak implementations.

When the true result is small and the single precision value is a non-zero *sub-normal*, the relative error grows as the true value nears 0.0 until `0.5 * pow(2,0)` or 1/2. Note this is considering the relative error as:

```
relative_error_IEEE = |true value - IEEE value|/IEEE value
```

When the IEEE value is zero or the relative error is determined as below, the relative error approaches infinity.

```
relative_error_true = |true value - IEEE value|/true value
```

---

<sup>*1</sup> Common calculations  like `+,-,*,/` should be within 0.5 ULP when the rounding mode is *round-to-nearest*.

Comment: The relative error could also be defined as |true value/true value - IEEE value/true value which approaches 1 as the true value approaches 0.  The absolute difference between the true result and the encoded single precision is at most (FLT_MAX - next_smallest_float(FLOAT_MAX))/2, not (FLT_MAX - next_smallest_float(FLOAT_MAX))

Comment: MAX_FLT is 340282346638528859811704183484516925440.0, not +/-3.4028235... × 1038. the +/- indicates 2 values, which did you mean?  what do you mean by ... in this context?  The range is 2*MAX_FLT, not MAX_FLT.

Comment: @andrew A factor of 2 or not in `FLT_MAX - next_smallest_float(FLOAT_MAX)` depends on rounding mode.  Given all rounding modes, not only round-to-nearest, the max difference is `FLT_MAX - next_smallest_float(FLOAT_MAX)`.  With round-to-nearest, it is `/2` as you suggest.

Comment: @Andrew "finite range +/-3.4028235... × 10^38' implies [-3.4028235... × 10^38 to +3.4028235... × 10^38], as rounded values. - albeit without being precise to the ones digits.